# Javascript event propagation not working as expected

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-propagation

```
window.document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        setTimeout(function(){e.target.dispatchEvent(e);}, 2000);
}, true);

<button onclick="console.log('test')">test</button>
```

Why isn't the event firing after 2 seconds? (it never fires)

Comment: Because `dispatchEvent` does not call the stuff that you have in attribute on the `button`. It calls functions attached to listeners. Do you expect `console.log('test')` to work after 2 seconds? It would not happen.

Comment: its an onclick attribute, that's a click event, and it works if I don't stop the propagation of the event.

Comment: Add a console.log in the `addEventListener`. I have a suspicion that the dispatchEvent gets intercepted by the event listener and you're continually stopping propagation (thus the onclick never fires) and dispatching a new event after 2 seconds.

Comment: Nope, if I add console.log it works.

Comment: It was a year or more ago, so my memory is foggy, but I had a similar problem. FWIW what I remember is that this type of **re**dispatching is not possible/supported. `dispatchEvent` is, I seem to recall, limited to dispatching new events that you create yourself.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [*W3C DOM Level 3 Events Specification*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/), [event flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20140925/#event-flow) has 3 phases: capture, target and bubble. And if "*…Event.stopPropagation() has been called prior to the dispatch, all phases must be skipped*".

So since *stopPropagation* has been called before the event is dispatched, no phase will executed, including the **target phase**.